# Can I ask a question here if I'm not a parent?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I'm not a parent, but I'm just curious to know some info. Is it wrong to ask a question pretending to be a parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think you should *pretend* to be a parent, but it’s certainly fine to ask a question even if you’re not a parent. Do read the help center for exactly what’s on topic; we prefer questions about real situations or realistic at least, but if it’s a reasonable question it’s fine regardless of your parenting status.

Feel free to ask in chat if you're not sure about a particular question!